# How to generate multiple files from a search by date?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following situation, in the database the content column where the entire structure of an XML file is stored.

I need to make it generate multiple files according to the amount of records.

**Example:** If on 02/07/2019 there are 08/02/2019 you have 100 records, I want you to generate 100 files.

The way I'm doing it, it's generating 1 file, with 100 information inside.

The code I created today is the one I can't think of how to generate by registration.

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=TestXML.xml"); 

    $data1 = '2019-02-07';
    $data2 = '2019-02-08';
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=73519225000122", "root", "");

    $buscar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT conteudo FROM xml WHERE modelo = '55' AND data_gravacao BETWEEN date('$data1') AND date('$data2')");
    $buscar->execute();
    $linha = $buscar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    foreach ($linha as $key => $value) {
        echo count($key);
    }
?>
```

Comment: currently, does your loop (foreach ($ linha as $ key => value)) ... perform an iteration expected 100 times?

Comment: how should the 100 files be named?, and what do you mean by "generate by registration." ?

Comment: There is a column called content, it is stored a complete structure of an XML, so I need that for each record, an XML is generated, soon after completing all the records, the folder would be compressed and already downloaded.

Comment: Well then you need to implement the “compressing” part first. You can not send multiple separate files to the client in response to one single HTTP request.

Comment: Yes, I can not do this with the client, so I created this snippet and seek a way how to do it correctly, which is to put them all in one folder, compress the folder and then download it automatically.

Comment: Please share more details. In the current example, you don't "create" any file

Comment: In select up the field type is blob when used together with:

header ('Content-Type: application / xml; charset = utf-8');
    header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename = TestXML.xml");

When you print with echo, it generates a file from the blob field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, after understanding, you'd have something like that ..

```
  $dirPath="xxxxw/whereyouwant/tmpxxx";

  $generated=arrray(); // or =[];
  foreach ($linha as $key => $value) {
        $content=$value['content'];
        $fileName=$dirPath.'/fileBaseName'.$key;
        $result=file_put_contents ($fileName , $content);
        if ($result===FALSE) {
          // handle error, throw exception, etc...
        } else {
            $generated[]=$fileName; // remember this file
          }
  }

  // then zip all (but it's another problem...
  // you have now a $generated array with all files to zip and send..
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, you helped me a lot! You can leave what is missing now! Thank you very much big hug!